# How to always cut the PID from `ps aux` command?

Tags: grep, cut, ps

I'd like to get the pid from my processes.  I do `ps aux | cut -d ' ' -f 2` but I notice that sometimes it gets the pid and sometimes it does not:

```
[user@ip ~]$ ps aux 
user  2049  0.5 10.4 6059216 1623520 ?     Sl   date   8:48 process 
user 12290  0.3  6.9 5881568 1086244 ?     Sl   date  2:30 
[user@ip ~]$ ps aux | cut -d ' ' -f 2 

12290
[user@ip ~]$ ps aux |  cut -d ' ' -f 3
2049
```

notice that the first `cut` command is piping it to `2` whereas the second one is piping it to `3`.  How do I pick out the PID from these without having to know which number to use (`2` or `3`)?

Can someone please tell me the difference between these and why it picks up one and not the other?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`-d ' '` means using a single space as delimiter. Since there're 1 space before 2049 and 2 spaces before 12290, your command get them by `-f 2` and `-f 3`.

I recommend using `ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` to get those pids.

Or you can use `tr` to squeeze those spaces first
 `ps aux | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

Answer (score 11):

You can always use **pgrep** to get process's PID

E.g PIDs with PS AUX

```
wix@wsys:~$ ps aux | grep sshd
root      1101  0.0  0.0  72304  3188 ?        Ss   Oct14   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      6372  0.0  0.1 105692  7064 ?        Ss   06:01   0:00 sshd: wix [priv]
wix       6481  0.0  0.1 107988  5748 ?        S    06:01   0:00 sshd: wix@pts/1
root      6497  0.0  0.1 105692  7092 ?        Ss   06:01   0:00 sshd: wix [priv]
wix       6580  0.0  0.1 107988  5484 ?        S    06:01   0:00 sshd: wix@pts/2
wix       6726  0.0  0.0  13136  1044 pts/1    S+   06:12   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Now just pgrep to get PIDs

```
wix@wsys:~$ pgrep sshd
1101
6372
6481
6497
6580
wix@wsys:~$
```

Comment: How does this relate to the OP's question ?

Comment: I figure the goal is to get the PIDs so why not use a tool at hand rather then using complex chain of commands.

Comment: He did not specify what his final intent is, but since collecting the PIDs of ALL your processes seems pointless, I guess you might be right.

Comment: Even if you want all processes you can do pgrep ""

Comment: how to do for `/sbin/lvmetad -f` pgrep will not be showing the PID's

Comment: `pgrep --full` worked great for me. I was looking for particular python script invocations, and regular pgrep wasn't cutting it.

Comment: pgrep does not always show the processes, you may need -f

Answer (score 7):

You can use the option *-o* to print only the pid:

```
ps -u user -o pid
```

Answer (score 4):

For all the processes, the above answers are good (`awk` one, for example), but for some specific program processes, I am doing something differently.

You can potentially do: `ps aux | grep <program-name>  | awk '{print $2}'`, but you would get 2 answers... Example (and a bit of debug):

```
$ ps aux | grep gnome-terminal  | awk '{print $2}'
9679
93820
$ ps aux | grep gnome-terminal  | awk '{print $2 " --> " $11 " " $12 " " $13}'  # just debug
9679 --> /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server  
93986 --> grep --color=auto gnome-terminal
```

So, instead, `pgrep -f <program-name>` can be used, and the grep PID itself will not appear... Example (and, again, a bit of debug):

```
$ pgrep -f gnome-terminal
9679
$ pgrep -f -l gnome-terminal  # just debug
9679 gnome-terminal-
```